# Is it possible to access external storage in platform-independent code in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm mainly developing for Android, so I know one can access the external storage of an Android device in Xamarin.Forms using `Android.Content.Context.GetExternalFilesDir`.

I know its possible to access the internal storage platform-independently using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`, but is it also possible to do the same for external storage?

I know the use case might be prettty limited, as iOS doesn't allow any non-jailbreaked access to the file system anyway, but wouldn't it still be good to write to external file systems without having to implement it for each platform? Couldn't one just write to the root app files directory and let the OS API handle the rest? I'm pretty new so don't laugh too much at the stupid question.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Forms does not provide the api to access External storage , we have to implement it in each specific platform ,check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows.

Comment: Alright that answers my question, thanks! Feel free to put it in an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: I'm also curious, where in the documentation does it say that? I read that page and couldn't find that point definitively stated anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms does not provide the api to access External storage , we have to implement it in each specific platform ,please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1):

**Android**

My code for the Android project, I use a class name like "Storage", extend the Interface you create in the Xamarin.Forms project and use:

```
public void SaveFile(string fileName)
        {
            string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + "Example .txt created using Xamarin.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + "Example .txt created using Xamarin.");
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// To receive file from Android Phone
        /// </summary>
        public string ReceiveFile(string fileName)
        {
            string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            return filePath;
        }
```

**Xamarin.Forms Interface:**

```
public interface IArchivos
    {
        void SaveFile(string fileName);
        string ReceiveFile(string fileName);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is going to probably be helpful for the android implementation, thanks! But as i understand it, I can't use this to implement it cross-platform, as Cole said right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, at least at this time. It is my understanding that external storage types and locations are just very different for each platform, or at least with permissions, you must access the external storage from each native project. At least with a work around you can achieve anything in Xamarin.Forms, I am sure it will keep getting better as this is Microsoft's main mobile cross-platfrom.

Answer (score 1):

**Xamarin For Android Implementation.**

```
// First take storage permission.
// var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
// status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

var fullPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "file_name.txt");
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fullPath);

// Writing data to file.

var fsToWrite = fi.Open(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
var sw = new StreamWriter(fsToWrite);
sw.WriteLine("Another line from streamwriter");
sw.Close();
fsToWrite.Close();

// Reading data from file.

var fsToRead = fi.Open(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
var sr = new StreamReader(fsToRead);
string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
fsToRead.Close();

System.Console.WriteLine("Data from : ", fileContent);
```